# How to plus more 20 px to old elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to plus more `20 px` to old elements using javascript ?

on my `id="test"` have `padding-top: 30px;`

```
<p id="test" style=" padding-top: 30px; " >This is the paragarph</p>
```

I want to plus more 20px. by using this code

```
(function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("test");
  var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);

  padding_top_value = style.paddingTop;
  padding_top_value_new = padding_top_value + 20;

  alert(padding_top_value_new);     
})();
```

but not work , how can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/2sd9cu37/

Comment: use javascript `parseInt();`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please choose it as best :)

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript's `parseInt();` function which is used to parse a string to an integer.

Change your script to this:

```
(function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("test");
  var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);

  padding_top_value = parseInt(style.paddingTop, 10);
  padding_top_value_new = padding_top_value + 20;

  alert(padding_top_value_new);     
})();
```

Check this out too http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

**Update:**
Here is the code necessary to resize the `p` height.

```js
(function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("test");
  var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);
  p.style.paddingTop = parseInt(style.paddingTop, 10) + 20 + 'px';
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" style=" padding-top: 30px; ">This is the paragarph</p>
```

Tell me if I can possibly improve my answer ;)

Comment: Note: With `parseInt()`, it's generally recommended to specify the `radix` rather then letting the engine *guess* it from the input – `parseInt(style.paddingTop, 10);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `css` [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```js
 
var p = document.getElementById("test");
p.style.paddingTop = "calc(" + p.style.paddingTop + " + 20px)"
```

```html
<p id="test" style="padding-top:30px;">This is the paragarph</p>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sd9cu37/1/